# Check if is const on C++03

Tags: c++, c++03

How do I check if an object is const without C++11's `std::is_const`? As far as I know I shouldn't be `const_cast`ing an object that was **declared** const

Comment: *Subject to the restrictions in this section, an expression may be cast to its own type using a const_cast operator.* - 5.2.11/2

Comment: You actually misunderstood what you should and should not do. You **should not** cast away const-ness of an object that was originally declared as `const`. That being said, you cannot use `is_const` (either C++11 or your own) to detect this, as that will only deal with the type of the reference you have, which might be more const-qualified than the actual object.

Comment: Note: An object const(ness) is defined at compile time. This is **NOT** a runtime feature. Thus the term `check if an object is const` is not really the correct terminology. You can generate different code based on template parameters const(ness) but this is a compile time feature. Note: casting (include const_cast) is a runtime activity not compile time.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'm not sure I follow. Only `dynamic_cast` has runtime behavior, all others are simply compile-time type conversions.

Comment: @GManNickG: Badly worded. Its an operation applied to a run-time object.

Comment: Oh wow @GManNickG, awesome information, I had no idea about that. What about C-Style casts?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: A C-style cast is a combination of C++-style casts, tried in order until one works. No runtime overhead (because it never tries `dynamic_cast`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An example implementation for C++11's `is_const` is given on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const), and it looks like this:

```
template<class T> struct is_const          : false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_const<const T> : true_type {};
```

If you put this definition in your C++03 code, you can use `is_const` there as well, if you add definitions for `false_type` and `true_type` (thanks to mfonantini for pointing out the missing `true_type` and `false_type`). If you define them as follows, you'll get very close to the definition used in C++11:

```
struct true_type {
  static const bool value = true;
  typedef bool value_type;
  typedef true_type type;
  operator value_type() const { return value; }
};

struct false_type {
  static const bool value = false;
  typedef bool value_type;
  typedef false_type type;
  operator value_type() const { return value; }
};
```

The only difference is that the static `value` is a mere `const`, not a `constexpr`, but note that it is a constant expression nevertheless and can be used as template argument. So for all practical purposes, the definition above should work in C++03.

Regarding the last part of your question: There is actually no problem casting a non-const type to const. (Illegal situations can, however, arise with pointers to pointers or references to pointers, e.g. `T**` cannot be cast to `const T**`.)

Comment: `std::true/false_type` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: @mfontanini Yes, I didn't think of that. I've added the necessary workaround to the answer. Thanks.